# xymatrix using lyx

Tags: lyx, xy-pic

I'm trying to draw in LyX, using `XYmatrix`. I'm using it with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> command, and then using the `\xymatrix` to start "drawing" what i want. I'm having a problem doint a "hookrightarrow" between to sets, and I wonder if anyone knows how to do it using LyX.

I do know that i need to write something like `- \ar@{^(->}` , but my main problem is with the `^` sign.. is it needs to be <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>, or should it be something else?

I know that its a silly question, but im really stuck, and haven't found the answer in the previous questions that was asked.
Can you give me a hand with it?

Comment: Yes, it's the ordinary "circumflex", usually shift-6.

Comment: And the (-> that comes after are suppose to be "inside" the blank that appears when im pressing the shift-6?

Comment: I know nothing about LyX, but I suppose you have to type this into an ERC (or whatever they call it). If pressing shift-6 only allows to specify an exponent, then the fault is in LyX.

Comment: It works. only the '(' sign needs to be in the exponent.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In case you're not aware, there's a manual in LyX. Go to Help > Specific Manuals > XY pic

Answer (score 2):

Lyx's support for XYpic is quite good (not perfect though). For the basic things like formatting arrows (head, tail, shaft, position, labels, etc.) you just use the commands as written in any XYpic manual, and just let Lyx do its thing. If the command requires a superscript/subscript, just type it in the lyx box that opens.